# Finding profiles in sql

Tags: php, mysql, profile

i am trying to make a profile page. I was just testing by getting a profile name from the url box and getting info bout this user, but i just get info about all the users in my database. If i for example type user1, it gives me all the info of all the users in the database. if i specifically want to find this user 1 and only his info, how do i do this?

```
<?php $fname=$_GET["fname"] ?>
<html>
<head>
<title> <? echo $fname ?> 
</title>
</head>
<body>
<BR><BR>
<h3>
<?php if (false === $registerOrLoginNeeded):?>
<? echo "User - ".$fname." <BR> ";
?>

<?php 
 mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
 echo "Real Name - ".$info['name'] . " <BR>";
 echo "Email - ".$info['email'] . " <br> " ;
 echo "Location - ".$info['location'] . " <br> " ;
 echo "Gender - ".$info['gender'] . " <br> " ;

 } 
 ?>
 <? else: endif ?>
```

Comment: `select * from users where username=$username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your username field is `username` just change your query to:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '$fname' LIMIT 1");
```

You need to tell your database that you want only one record for **EXACTLY** that user. That's why we add the `WHERE` clause. And our query becomes *SELECT EVERYTHING FROM TABLE USERS WHERE USER'S USERNAME IS EQUAL TO THE PASSED VARIABLE FROM URI*.

How to check if the user is found

```
if(mysql_num_rows($data) > 0)
{
//DISPLAY USER INFO
}
else
{
//NO USER FOUND
}
```

Comment: If this is the answer to your question please "Accept it" by clicking on the tick. Glad it helped you!

Comment: And is there a way to give an error when i don't get any results? something like: No user found with that name

Comment: **please** realise that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. People will be able to expose private data and delete anything from your database by passing a 'special' username! You should use prepared statements and no longer use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. More on SQL injection can be found here: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html